# An application of Rouche Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble in understanding the following proof of a problem from my complex analysis class:

What is the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $f(z)=z^5+48z+64$ has a root in the disk $|z|<r$?

Proof: For $|z|=1$, it is routine to show that $f$ has no roots inside $|z|=1$ using Rouche's theorem.

For $|z|=2$, let $g(z)=-48z$, then $|f(z)+g(z)|=|z^5+64| \leq |z|^5+64=96=48|z|=|g(z)|\leq |f(z)|+|g(z)|$. For equality to hold throughout, we must have $z=2$ and $f(z)=0$. Since $z=2$ is not a root of $f(z)$, one of the inequality is strict, i.e. on $|z|=2$, $|f(z)+g(z)|< |f(z)|+|g(z)|$. By Rouche's theorem, $f$ has one root inside $|z|=2$, hence $r=2$.

My question is, why for the equality to hold for all $|z|=2$, we must have $z=2$ and $2$ is a root of $f(z)$? Secondly, even it is true, isn't it only mean that $|f(z)+g(z)|< |f(z)|+|g(z)|$ for some $|z|=2$ only, instead of all $|z|=2$?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the proof shows that, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=2$, the inequality $|f(z)+g(z)|\leq |f(z)|+|g(z)|$ holds, and we want to show that it is a strict inequality (i.e. equality is impossible for *all* $|z|=2$). Suppose equality holds for some $|z|=2$. Notice that $|z^5+64|=|z|^5+64$ (part of the string of inequalities) only if $z$ and $64$ have the same argument, i.e. $z\in\mathbb{R}$ so $z=2$. But you also have the inequality $|g(z)|\leq |f(z)|+|g(z)|$, where equality holds only if $f(z)=0$. But $f(2)\neq 0$, so this is a contradiction and thus the assumption that equality holds for some $|z|=2$ must have been false. Therefore inequality holds for *all* $|z|=2$, and you can apply Rouché's Theorem.

Comment: This is essentially correct. However, for equality to hold in the statement
$$ |z^5 + 64| = |z^5| + 64 = |z|^5 + 64,$$ it is only required that $z = 2 \omega_{5}^k$ where $\omega_{5}$ denotes the fifth root of unity and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This shows you need to check five places for $f(z) \neq 0$. However, it's almost immediate since $f(2 w^{k}_{5}) = 65 + 96 w_{5}^{k}$ cannot be zero.